# What is a good point-and-click way to draw simple dot and line 3D graphs?

Tags: 3d

I'd like to draw simple, 3D dot and line graphs like the following:

[image]

I would prefer the resulting images to be rotatable. I am aware of coded solutions such as [TikZ](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/3d-graph-model/), but I want something more fluid and point-and-click so that I can change it very easily and use it to help me think. What is an open-source solution for this?